# How do I solve $\sin(z)=5$ for all complex $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I solve $$\sin(z)=5$$  for all complex $z$?

I have tried using the definition of $\sin$ in terms of $\exp$ but I don't get far.  I have tried setting $z=x+iy$ and considering trig identities but this didn't help either, neither did the Taylor series for $\sin$. thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate at all on how far you got with the exponentials definition of $\sin$? : ) Some working would perhaps help us to diagnose your problem better

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Are you saying I should focus on the definition as that's the way to go? (sorry a bit frustrated i've spent a long time on this)

Comment: Yes, the exponentials definition is the right way to go. The initial hint is to rearrange and solve for $e^{iz}$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen lol now it looks too easy : ) i think not knowing how to tackle it was the main problem, thank you!

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166562